Data not uploading on IPFS network using Helia
I'm trying to import helia using npm.
My goal is to upload string data, but the generated cid doesn't seem to be added to ipfs network, because
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafkreigonb4ic54vgx4md6adzwmtwgsk3g2zea3qpeyvzy5245jaqxc4bq
keeps returning 504 gateway timeout error.
Is there any example I can refer to?
Please help...
As a test, I tried running
https://github.com/haixuxu/ipfs-helia-rpc
but it doesn't seem to work.
Pre-uploaded cid works, but when I try to change the test string to encode, it's doesn't upload.

This is likely due to several factors that could be at play, including firewalls on your computer or network preventing peer to peer connections. Even beyond that, the gateway you are trying to use is a public gateway that is not going to be peered with your IPFS node, so it could take a while for the data to propagate and be discovered. This is why most people building on IPFS use a pinning service for speed and reliability.
